# How to abort 403 when user visits not authenticated area in Nova

Tags: laravel, policy, provider, laravel-nova

In my laravel/nova app, I need to set something like that: 
users must see own posts, can't able to see others posts.
For example:

```
| id | name        | user_id |
|----|-------------|---------|
| 1  | POST1       |    1    |
| 2  | POST2       |    1    |
| 3  | POST3       |    2    |
```

In this situation if we are the id=1 user, just see first two posts. 
This is easy, I read the doc and made it with this.

In the related model I did this:

```
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    if(auth()->user()->hasRole('admin'))
    {
        return $query;
    }
    if(!auth()->user()->hasRole('admin'))
    {
        return $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
    }
}
```

But I still see this like that:
..../resources/posts/3

I must unable to see and I need get 403 page. Where should I put this statement?
I was created policy earlier. In posts policy,

```
public function view(User $user, Company $company)
{
    return auth()->user()->hasRole(['supervisor', 'admin']);
}
```

This doesn't solve the issue too. These are what I tried, its just not displaying. But I need to abort 403 or smt.

Can anybody help me i'll glad so much. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current policy condition `auth()->user()->hasRole(['supervisor', 'admin'])`, checks only whether authenticated user has given roles. It doesn't check for own post.

Update your post policy condition as below. Also note the second parameter is instance of `Post` not `Company`

```
public function view(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $post->user_id == $auth()->user()->id;
}
```